# Shapely: self intersecting buffer area

Tags: python, shapely

In shapely I want to draw a movement profile of a person. While the person moves through the area, it "discovers" its environment step by step. I use a buffer to model this in shapely.

So basically, at the moment its a LineString with a Buffer.

However, I want to know, how efficiently the person did its discovery process. Therefore, the self-overlapping area of the developed LineString buffer is very interesting.

The more often a buffer overlaps itself, the more inefficient it is. With this I want to simulate different movement profiles and compare them with each other.

I found somewhere how to find the intersecting points of the LineString, but for the buffer, I did not find anything. Especially when the buffer is from the same LineString object and are not two or more different objects

How can this (efficiently) be done with shapely?

I would be good to have something like:

- The area of the self overlapping buffer
- How often the buffer overlaps itself at this point (represents: the person "visited" this area n times)
- Nice to have: a heat map where the most overlapping places are for example red and less overlapping is yellow and no overlapping is green

Any ideas?